# replace only some characters in a string

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a way in Java to replace a matched character from a sequence without a loop.

Example

```
   String x = ""
   String pattern = "12"
   String ex1 = "1254"
   x = ex1.replace(pattern, "");
   System.out.print(x)
   Output:
   54
   In this case 1254 a match is found: 12
```

However,

```
   String x = ""
   String pattern = "12"
   String ex1 = "154"
   x = ex1.replace(pattern, "");
   System.out.print(x)
   Output:
   154
   In this case no replacement takes place.
   The desired output in this case would be:

   54 

   because only 1 is found from the pattern
```

This is because the pattern should fully match in the word. However, is there a function where only the matched characters from the pattern will be replaced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)

```
x = ex1.replaceAll("[12]", "");
```

Comment: How about if I have to use the variable pattern where the sequence is held? This one ("[" +  pattern + "]" does not work

Comment: Are you using `replaceAll` as opposed to `replace`?

Comment: I was using replace rather than replaceAll. Now it works. Thanks. Also, I don't quite understand why my question was negated??? I have formulated the question correctly and provided as many details as I could??

Comment: Maybe for poor research effort